# SQL : filter on case-statement data-substitution in the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

If I have a table called 'Beasties', and I want to do some conditional substitution of the data values in a column, eg Animal, and then filter on that column, I would try to do this...

```
SELECT 
   (CASE Animal 
    WHEN 'Horse' THEN 'Zebra' 
    ELSE Animal
    END) AS Species
FROM Beasties 
WHERE Species='Zebra'
```

But T-SQL will not allow the WHERE clause, it would only let me use Animal instead of Species.  How can I filter on a renamed (and therefore edited) column value?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: I suppose the important question is why would you want to do this? Is there an easier way round your problem? A Species table?

Comment: Because I have to update horrible legacy code, and life is not fair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this:

```
SELECT 
   (CASE Animal 
    WHEN 'Horse' THEN 'Zebra' 
    ELSE Animal
    END) AS Species
FROM Beasties 
WHERE 'Zebra'=(CASE Animal WHEN 'Horse' THEN 'Zebra'  ELSE Animal END)
```

Comment: Had to be this way, all to do with the execution order, right?  OK, good answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could just stick it in a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
       (CASE Animal 
        WHEN 'Horse' THEN 'Zebra' 
        ELSE Animal
        END) AS Species
    FROM Beasties
)
WHERE Species='Zebra'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a particularly elegant way to do it, but this should work if there isn't:

```
WHERE Animal IN ('Horse', 'Zebra')
```